# Neighbour search with kd trees

Tags: python, numpy, tree, kdtree

I have a dataset of points in R^3. I'm able to build a kd-tree with python's subpackage `spatial`
(see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point.html))
and performing a neighbour search (all points within distance r from the query point).

What I don't get is the following:

When I build the tree from the dataset, this is done by searching the median of the points of the dataset and using this as the root node. I understand well how the search is done for the root node of a k-d-tree. What I don't understand is how the search is performed for points which are not the root of the tree. I tried to find out but failed at this.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Nearest_neighbour_search)?

Comment: There's even an animation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#/media/File:KDTree-animation.gif)